# C#, OAuth2 fails in debug mode but works ok when running executable

Tags: c#, oauth, visual-studio-debugging

I have this piece of code: (username and password are changed in the example)

```
string un="test@test.com";
string pw="hq23@3";
string url="https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth/token";
string cliid = "3MVG9yZ.WNae345QAvlJ.HwD94PbdkgMvpoq2IgBi3CPP.r8EfNQB.uAAm72swYrQSaG5TdhXseqChQiIBvox";
string clisec = "33861436554340449385";
HOauth2 h = new HOauth2(lurl,cliid,clisec);
HOauthResult r = h.authenticate(un, pw);
Console.WriteLine(r.getErm());
Console.WriteLine(r.getAccessToken());
Console.ReadKey();
```

If I build the project and run executable I get expected output:

> NoError
>   00DA0000000tuBSm!ARsAQQZEdOXXXZAqmYtG.Sj9.6d7_DYdrdKqdnoAkANT4I3Lb4F3Pgz0AYSkRWVJKTmy3cqbGWcV2gSYCxvAbXkg6mJ8l_jK

However, running the project in `VS` in `Debug/Release` mode the same piece of code produces output:

> invalid_grant|authentication failure

It is driving me crazy, I can not debug the rest of the code.
Has anybody experienced similar behavior, and was there solution to the problem.
I enabled `system.diagnostics` in `App.config` and compared data streams to the server in both cases and they are the same , byte for byte.

Comment: Please delete the Bin\Debug folder, and then clean and rebuild your project, view the result, as you said that you get this issue during debugging, does it still has this issue if you just run your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)" in your VS IDE?

Comment: Hi Jack, I did as you suggested but it still behaves the same. I set up break point at Console.WriteLn...  line and it fails when ran wit F5. Running it with Ctrl-F5 works without problem.

Comment: No class HOauth2/HOauthResult, sorry for that I couldn't repro this issue. Please try to enable Exception settings under menu Debug->Windows->Exception Settings, and then debug your app in your VS IDE, view the result. Maybe it has certain unhanded Exception. Do you have other VS Environment debug this app? At least, we could know that whether it is related to the VS IDE or others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try code on the different machine

Comment: Do you get any latest information for it? Does it have this issue in other VS machine?

Comment: I figured it out, it was not problem with the code, instead it was type of encryption used for https. The remote server supports TLS1.2, and my code did not specify anything, So when running from VS it was using default VS setting , that was TLS1.0 and it was failing, but the error message was completely useless (400 bad request). When running the exe file from cmd, it would use default machine setting that was TLS1.2 and it would work. I had programmatically to force TLS1.2 setting ServicePointManager to correct value. Everything is good now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, add your solution as an answer(not a comment), so you could mark it as the answer, and it would be helpful for other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the code but with development environment. VS for some reason uses TLS1.0 as default protocol, while for the machine itself it is TLS1.2
After forcing TLS1.2 in code, setting value to ServicePointManager, everything started working. It took some time to figure this out since error messages delivered by remote server that was accepting TLS1.2 were not descriptive (400 Bad request).
The real solution would be to set VS to use default machine setting  for the protocol.